# i5 or i7 CPU for ArcMap on desktop PC with 12GB RAM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, hardware-recommendations

I can get a good deal on a desktop computer with a 128GB SSD and 12GB of RAM.  The CPU is i5 (not sure which i5).  I have a huge map that I am working on with ArcMap.  Do you think the i5 PC will be fast enough or should I get a PC with an i7 CPU?

Comment: Supported/recommended requirements for ArcGIS Desktop: http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/system-requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends ultimately on sort of data you will be processing in addition to what you do outside of GIS work (gaming etc).

I would read online reviews of the respective processors and compare their performance that way. Always go for better than less.

Comment: Thanks, I did as you suggested and it sounds like the i7 will work better for graphics-intensive applications like ArcMap.  The PC will only be used to ArcMap, not gaming. I will also look into buying a graphics card.